# Setting bold math font with LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, latex

I like to use a sans-serif math font to typeset my documents.
I use LuaLaTeX as a compiler and Fira Sans Light as may main font.

As Fira Math Sans is a little bit too bold to my taste and I'm well aware Fira Sans Math Light does not include all the glyphs I need, here's what I do :

- I load the default math font ;
- then Fira Sans Math Light just for the digits and the latin letters.

It works OK for me... But the problem is I can't get `\boldfont` anymore.

Here's what I put in my package :

```latex
\RequirePackage[math-style=french,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont{FiraMath-Light.otf}[range={up, it,sfup,sfit}]
```

Any advise would be very much appreciated.